# Jquery background for a dropdown list

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a dropdown list and I would like to make a specific item in the list have a background color of yellow and I'm not sure of the jquery code for this.

Here's the script:

```
<script language="text/Javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('select[id="ddlParticipants"]'.rows[2].bgColor = "#FFFF00")
    })
</script>
```

and here's the dropdown list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParticipants" runat="server" Width="300px"
     AutoPostBack="True" 
     onselectedindexchanged="ddlParticipants_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     meta:resourcekey="ddlParticipantsResource1">
     <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:Resources, Select %>" 
         meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="---I am a NEW participant---" Value="0" 
         meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to make the listitem that reads "I am  New Participant" yellow.
Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible with the markup you have. `<asp:dropdownlist>` renders as `<select ..>` elements in HTML and you cannot style the `<options>` inside the `<select>` element. You would have to resort to some other trick, using `li` or something similar.